# Unable to install npm /react /node js on mac terminal

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops

I been unable to run npm install on my mac terminal or VSTS code. see below the commands that are trying to run

1. npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com--always-auth false
2. vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc

error in here

> I have an format error on the second command

```
vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc zsh: exec format error: vsts-npm-auth
```

3. Run: `npm install`
4. run npm start`

As you can see, I can not even past the first command.

I had try
clear the proxy
assign a proxy
And my network is completely fine, I ping https://registry.npmjs.com and it works ok I also did

-npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.com--always-auth/vsts-npm-auth failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.com--always-auth
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Comment: Hi @Pxaml, is any update here? Feel free to let me know the latest news.

Comment: Nope ! I wish . I end up using a windows. I couldn't figure this out

Comment: Hi @Pxaml, Could you please share the latest error message here? A screenshot is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

> **vsts-npm-auth** is not supported for Linux/Mac.

*from [Azure DevOps Documentation / Set up your client's npmrc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops#linux-or-mac)*

1. First option is generating a token

[Set up authentication on your dev box / Linux or Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops#linux-or-mac)

[In the Project setup section, select Other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKfTN.png)

2. Second option is platform agnostic library

**better-vsts-npm-auth**

Comment: `better-vsts-npm-auth` works perfectly on macOS - also supports yarn if you use `.yarnrc.yml` - update the `npmAuthToken` attribute with the refresh token generated from `~/.npmrc`

Comment: better-vsts-npm-auth is for sure the best way to setup on the Mac IMO.

Comment: Thanks, better-vsts-npm-auth works perfect for Debia/Linux +100

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space before the `--always-auth`:

```sh
npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false
# Space was missing here -----------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you , Iam missing something on the second command as well  vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc 
zsh: exec format error: vsts-npm-auth

Comment: It didn't work on mac. It looks that on mac vsts-npm-auth is installed in the npm as a windows executable.